# SAML IDP using wildfly

Tags: saml, keycloak, picketlink

I am trying to authenticate users on a Wildfly application using a SAML SSO.

I do not have the possibility to choose the IDP, so no keycloak option available.

I was looking at picketlink, but I have read that is gone to be merged with keycloak and not really further improved.  I know keycloak as IDP but as SP I have only used the wildlfy adapter.

So, is the replacement of picketlink for SPs the keycloak wildlfy adapter? I have not seen any docs on how to use it with non-keycloaks clients.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use any SAMLv2 service provider implementation, it just a matter which kind of integration your need within JBoss (WebContainer/EJB). You could even frontend JBoss with Apache httpd server and use mod_auth_mellon as SAML SP, see https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/securing_apps/topics/saml/saml-overview.html If you are using Spring you could also integrate Spring Security SAML extension as SAML SP implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is more about, how is really Keycloak really replacing picketlink for an SP. Picketlink can connect with any IDP, but as far as I know the Keycloak SPs adapters, are only able to work correctly with keycloak and not for example with BIG-IP. SInce the official recommendation into picketlink web site is to move to keycloak, I guess I am missing something...

Comment: I would be very astonished if the 'Keykloak adapter' can only interact with a Keykloak SAML IdP.
>Keycloak is based on standard protocols and provides support for OpenID Connect, OAuth 2.0, and SAML.

Comment: Of course you can only use Picketlink SAML adapter, but Picketlink is not maintained anymore.

Comment: I will give a try to the adapter then. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use keycloak-saml adapter wit a third party IdP server https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/08/27/using-keycloak-instead-of-picketlink-for-saml-based-authentication/